# How can i upload image to webapp/resources/images/ directory using spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i have upload image that is saved in a local fold in c:/temp
i want to save it to classpath of project :webapp/resources/images/ 
my controller class is :

```
@Controller
public class AdminCtrl {

private static String UPLOAD_LOCATION = "C:/temp/";
@Autowired
FileValidator fileValidator;

@InitBinder("fileBucket")
protected void initBinderFileBucket(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(fileValidator);
}
//--------------------------POST IMAGE -------------------------------------   -----------------------------

 @RequestMapping(value = "/administration/parametres/profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String profilePage(@Valid FileBucket fileBucket,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap model) throws IOException {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("validation errors");
        return "redirect:/administration/parametres/profile?error";
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fetching file");
        MultipartFile multipartFile = fileBucket.getFile();
         Now do something with file...
        FileCopyUtils.copy(fileBucket.getFile().getBytes(), new File(UPLOAD_LOCATION + fileBucket.getFile().getOriginalFilename()));
        String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        model.addAttribute("fileName", fileName);
        return "redirect:/administration/parametres/profile?success";
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to do this? if it is about static content, you can map it to another folder in the system and let spring mvc access it, change part of the webapp is not a good idea, because how could you update your webapp?

Comment: i want image to be in the project classpath because i will use it in onother function in the project

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write or save anything to the classpath.
The classpath is just a string with jars and paths, separated by semikolon.

Depending on where your app is started, the classpath looks different. If you run it from a war, there will be only jars in the classpath.

What you can do, is save the file to a well known location e.g. from the user.home directory. When you need to read it, you can pick it up from there.